# Elegantly use multiple different time methods additively?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to use multiple time methods in an additive way?

Example: if the desired result was the time 3 weeks and 2 days ago, is there anything like this?

```rb
3.weeks.and.2.days.ago
```

I also tried

```rb
3.weeks.2.days.ago
```

What's the most elegant/sensible way to do this?

The best way I could come up with was

```rb
(3 + 2/7.to_d).weeks.ago
```

or

```rb
23.days.ago
```

But is there a way to use multiple time methods (e.g. `weeks`, `days`, `hours` etc) in the same command to make it easier to read?

Comment: Note that some date / time operations aren't commutative. For example, `Date.parse('2021-04-30') + 1.month + 1.day` returns Mon, 31 May 2021 whereas `Date.parse('2021-04-30') + 1.day + 1.month` returns Tue, 01 Jun 2021.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ActiveSupport::Duration`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) does not have a `and` method or any other method defined that works like that.

But want you can do ist this:

```
(3.weeks + 2.days).ago
#=> 2021-02-12 11:06:40.087082 +0100
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also [`advance`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-advance) which returns a new date / time object based on the given options:

```
Time.current
#=> Sun, 07 Mar 2021 12:14:29 CET +01:00

Time.current.advance(weeks: -3, days: -2)
#=> Fri, 12 Feb 2021 12:14:29 CET +01:00
```

Options are `:years`, `:months`, `:weeks`, `:days`, `:hours`, `:minutes`, and `:seconds`.